# bind event before append jquery object

Tags: jquery

How can I bind event to a not jet printed jquery object?

Example my div is:

```
var $div = $("<div>my div</div>");
```

I want to bind a click to this not rendered div and then print it on DOM, something like:

```
$div.click(function(){alert("hello")});
$(body).append($div);
```

thx

Answer (score 4):

Your code is almost correct - you just forgot some quotes around `body`:

```
var $div = $("<div>my div</div>");
$div.click(function(){alert("hello")});
$('body').append($div);
```

Instead of `$('body')` you could also use `$(document.body)`

Comment: Is this always guaranteed to work? Why can I bind an event to an element not yet in the DOM - how does that work internally?

Comment: It's already a DOM element. Just not part of the document's tree yet. But the event is bound to that element and not the document so it doesn't really matter.